# Keyword 'AppiumLibrary.Open Application' expected 1 to 2 non-keyword arguments

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, robotframework

I use robotframework-appiumlibrary 1.2.5

```
==============================================================================
Open App                                                              | FAIL |
Keyword 'AppiumLibrary.Open Application' expected 1 to 2 non-keyword arguments,
got 5.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Test Script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL}     http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME}    Android
${PLATFORM_VERSION}    4.4.2
${DEVICE_NAME}    emulator-5554
${APP}            D:/asas.apk

*** Test Cases ***
Open App
    Open Application    ${REMOTE_URL}    ${PLATFORM_NAME}    ${PLATFORM_VERSION}    ${DEVICE_NAME}    ${APP}
    Sleep   10s
```

I want to know solution.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search revealed [this link](https://github.com/jollychang/robotframework-appiumlibrary/issues/28) which states:

> since 1.2.0 we update Open Application keyword, you can check it that
>   http://jollychang.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/doc/AppimuLibrary.html#Open%20Application
>   such as

```
Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion=4.2.2   deviceName=192.168.56.101:5555  app=${CURDIR}/demoapp/OrangeDemoApp.apk appPackage=com.netease.qa.orangedemo    appActivity=MainActivity
```